# Why isinstance(Test(), MyAbstractClass) return False even if I implement all abstract methods in Test class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

From some book, it says when we define a class and implement all abstract methods, even if the class is not inherited from abstract class, the isinstance() check will return True.
I try it on my local:

```
from collections import abc

class Test:
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

print(isinstance(Test(), abc.Sized))
```

Because there is only one abstract method in abc.Sized class:_*len*_, the output is True as expected.

But when I try to define my own abstract class, it fails:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

Class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_size(self):pass

class Test:
    def get_size(self):
        return 0

print(isinstance(Test(), MyAbstractClass))
```

The output is False. I need to register it if I want it to be True:

```
MyAbstractClass.register(Test)
```

Why? Why I check it with abs.Sized I don't need to register it but with my own defined abstract class, I have to register it?

Comment: The book is wrong, or you've misread it. The behavior you're looking for is not the default. You can implement it with `__subclasshook__`, but it doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way of getting Python to do the duck typing that you are looking for: anything that implements `get_size` is automatically an instance of your abstract class.

Many of pythons abstract base classes use this.

```
class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is MyAbstractClass:
            if any("get_size" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test` class should inherit `MyAbstractClass`.

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_size(self):pass

class Test(MyAbstractClass):
    def get_size(self):
        return 0

print(isinstance(Test(), MyAbstractClass))
```